# security and access wamp

Tags: apache, wamp

I was installed wamp server 2.5 on windows 8.1 64 bit edition.
In a browser if I type "localhost" every things are ok but if I have any project -- for example testapp-- and I type localhost/testapp in my browser I see :
"Access Denied".
how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Any hints in the webserver error log? Often this comes from incorrect permissions on the files or folder, I'd start with the log then check the permissions.

Comment: thanks for your reply.I add full control for "EverONE " user to sub folder. but still I see "Access Denied"

Comment: If your testapp is in the folder `\wamp\www\testapp` you should be able to access it using the url you mention! Do you have a `index.php` file in that folder? Have you changed anything in the httpd.conf file?

Comment: What about the error log?

Comment: It is almost NEVER a windows file permission issue, unles your system is oddly configured. It will be an Apache access problem.

Comment: I have index.php and do not change any configuration.